# adding firebase auth breaks gradle when in strange configuration

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

I am trying to use firebase messaging, auth and database in the same project, however when I try and add the auth dependence to gradle, as the firebase 'getting started' guide instructs, I get <strike>2308</strike> 298 errors all related to build dependencies.
here is my app specific build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.withheld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    // Enabling multidex support.
    //multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    //I originally had all the play services enabled but now as a comment suggested I mm trying split dependencies.
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

<strike>also any way that I could speed up building would be helpful</strike>

edit:

> I am still getting errors but this time they are about random com.google.android.gms: dependencies I have never heard of like

play-services-tasks

play-services-basement

LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar

and ones I have used previously like

com.android.support:support-v4

com.android.support:recyclerview-v7

> is there something that I did wronge to mess up my build enviroment, I am using android studios 2.1.2 on windows 8.1

Comment: You should never be using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` - that includes *every single Play Services library* - have you tried switching to the [split dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)

Comment: That at least explains the horrible build time, I will see if I can get the split dependencies to work.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Many developers make the mistake of using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'`.  Some are likely misled by the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and don't carefully read the section on selectively compiling APIs.  The documentation should more prominently highlight the risks of including `play-services:9.x.x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
```

Change all to 9.2.0 and check it once

Comment: I will try this when I get home.

Comment: I made the change and it gives me the exact same errors

Comment: Did you enable/check firebase from cloud ... Please check this link https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration:

**build.graddle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

**build.graddle (Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```